# How do I remove the shutdown button only on the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

I don't want anyone to be able to shut down my computer from the login screen. Can I remove the shutdown button at the top right corner *of the login screen* in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 8):

Even if you cannot hide the buttons, you can configure your system so that the `lightdm` user does not have permissions to shutdown or restart the system. Since the greeter runs as the `lightdm` user, this should solve your issue. Create two new files in `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d`, call them `disable-lightdm-shutdown.pkla` and `disable-lightdm-restart.pkla` and apply the contents as below. Note: You can also stick these into one file.

Shutdown:

```
[Disable Shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:lightdm
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Restart:

```
[Disable Restart]
Identity=unix-user:lightdm
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Comment: So, it seems to work for me in my VM.  It still goes through all the menus and then nothing happens.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` and edit it to contain

```
indicators=false
```

This will remove all indicator from login page.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any configuration tools for LightDM that I know of, and if there are, there certainly wouldn't be any way to remove that button.

Unless you want to rewrite LightDM yourself.

Comment: You'd actually be rewriting unity-greeter.  Lightdm is the backend and is a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

One could alway try modifying the `/usr/share/lightdm-gtk-greeter/greeter.ui` file (available in Debian 7, at least).