# How to disable shutdown/restart/hibernate without authentication

Tags: shutdown, authentication

I do not want to allow my desktop to shutdown/restart/hibernate without authentication. How can I achieve this? I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with unity. Most of the questions previously asked involved asking the opposite thing. I need help as I am a newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want the computer to ask for your password in order to carry a shutdown/restart/hibernate command?

Answer (score 0):

You wanna deny users to shutdown\hibernate eg. the system from the GUI or terminal?

[This should give you a hint of how to remove it from the login\switch-user GUI if that is your consern.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137336/how-do-i-remove-the-shutdown-button-only-on-the-login-screen) You could also do something like [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1427933), but it is to dirty if you ask me.

If the `sudo shutdown` eg is your concern? you should really rethink your design and do some extensive research on how sudo work.