# How to disable the shutdown, reboot and hibernate options in the lightdm loginscreen?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, shutdown, lightdm, hibernate

I'm currently building a kiosk system based on xubuntu 16.04 and have to lock it down, in order to do that I arrrived at the point where I want to disable the above mentioned option in the lightdm loginscreen.

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453479/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-from-lightdm-in-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137336/how-do-i-remove-the-shutdown-button-only-on-the-login-screen) both are not working. Is there a new way to do this in xubuntu 16.04?

Best regards

Comment: I've found a workaround: running lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings gives you the opportunity to remove the Power Menu entirely.

Comment: +1 for mentioning what did not work. But, please put the workaround in an answer and not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested this is my comment as the answer.

I've found a workaround: running lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings gives you the opportunity to remove the Power Menu entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

`sudo apt-get install light-gtk-greeter-settings`

After it installs, logout and log back in, then run `light-gtk-greeter-settings`, and tweak it to your liking.